# How to get into CWM Recovery in Samsung galazy star pro s7262

Tags: recovery-mode

As you have read the question; you know what I want.
I'm always getting into stock [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode) but I have flashed CWM via Odin v3.07.
I m using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) to get into [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode)because when I press `Vol up + home + power` buttons; nothing happens. Can someone please help quickly?

Comment: You need to hold Volume Up + Home and then Hold power until the phone vibrates, let go of the volume button but keep holding Home and Volume up, it should boot into recovery then. Holding them makes a difference. Alternatively can you simply go to Restart > Recovery from your device? If not since you are rooted you can install Wanam Xposed and then install a 4 way reboot (Reboot, Fast Reboot, Reboot to Recovery, Reboot to Download Mode).